# Is there anyway I an detect transparent pixels in an image using rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using Rmagick to generate icons for iOS. And for this I need to remove transparency. For now I am deactivating the alpha channel and flattening all the images. Here is the code I use for this.

```
app_store_icon = ImageList.new(app_store_icon_url)
app_store_icon.alpha(DeactivateAlphaChannel)
app_store_icon.flatten_images
```

But I would like to avoid this unnecessary steps if the user uploads a proper png image without transparency. So how do check if there are any transparency in the image and do the above stpes only if required?

Answer (score 2):

In command line Imagemagick, extract the alpha channel and test if its average is less than 1. If so, then it has transparency. If exactly 1, then no transparency.

```
value=$(convert image -alpha extract -format "%[fx:mean]" info:)

or

value=$(convert image -alpha extract -scale 1x1! -format "%[fx:u]" info:)

if [ "$value" = 1 ]; then
echo "opaque"
else
echo "transparent"
fi
```

Sorry, I do not know RMagick.

Comment: Can you please let me know what does this part mean? `-format "%[fx:mean]" info:)`. I checked rmagick manual and saw they have an alpha method with argument `ExtractAlphaChannel`. The explanation given is: Creates a grayscale mask of the image's shape by copying the alpha channel values into all the color channels, and then turning off the image's transparency. Where do I go from here to calculate the average?

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php. It computes the mean of the whole image and reports that back so that it can be put into a variable.

Comment: works perfectly! thanks for the link to docs also.. i also couldn't find any info on how these % tags work!

Comment: fx is the calculator in ImageMagick. It can be used to compute one value or process the whole image. See https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx_escapes and https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

Answer (score 0):

Try if this way is ok for you: composite the image to a white background of the image size. For example, given the alpha channel image `img.png`:

```
require 'rmagick'
include Magick

image = Magick::Image.read("img.png").first
w = image.columns
h = image.rows

if image.alpha?
  bg = Image.new(w,h) { self.background_color = "white" } # create a white background
  image = bg.composite(image, NorthWestGravity, 0, 0, OverCompositeOp) # compose
end

image.write("img_out.png")
```

Look for [rmagick constants](https://rmagick.github.io/constants.html).

Comment: But this also is wasting unnecessary resources right, I am trying to avoid that. I want to check for transparency and do these steps only if its detected

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the instance method `alpha?`: https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#alpha_q | In case, see my edit.

Comment: I just checked image.alpha? and it returns false for an image with transparency in it.

Comment: I tested some images and `alpha?` is working fine for me.